# What's the best way to search for a UPC code in a Database?

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, barcode

I have a UPC Database of 12-digit UPC-A formatted barcodes (1,900,000 records). Currently they're stored as a varchar(13) due to leading zeros. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I also have an WCF 4.0 API Method that goes and queries the database based on a UPC-A barcodes match.

- What's the best way to improve performance of UPC based queries
- What is the best way to store 12-Digit UPC-A Barcodes. Is my assumption to use varchar(12) okay?

**Edit: More Information**

Products

- ProductID *(int)*
- Barcode *(varchar(12))*
- Name *(varchar(50))*
- ImageUrl *(varchar(255))*

My code:

```
public JsonResult GetProductByCode(string code)
{
  DBEntities db = new DBEntities;

  Product product = (from prod in db.Products
                    where prod.Barcode == code
                    select prod).FirstOrDefault();

  return Json( product , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
}
```

Comment: It's hard to suggest improvements to performance when you haven't shown us what you're doing now. :) Also, please define "massive".

Comment: @KenWhite There some information for you!

Comment: ... yes but what **query** is being executed?

Comment: Can u please tell us where we can get a UPC database like that u have?

Comment: There can be 2 ways, Using Solr and other can be CouchDb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take an index on the barcode column as a given.

You could save space if you stored the codes as numbers. Space is time as less bytes can be read faster. Also, the lookup should be faster on numbers. The leading zeros can be reconstructed when needed as UPC-A is a fixed-length code.

Comment: Space isn't an issue here. It's only 1.9M rows, and since they're fixed-width it's more overhead padding with zeros and converting for display purposes than it is to just use characters. You'd also have to convert from a user-entered barcode (string) to a numeric, adding overhead again, before searching.

Comment: @Ken Space is always an issue. Dividing the physical size of an index on the UPC codes might decide between the needed parts of the index residing in 3rd level cache or RAM. Do you understand the implications of the cache hierarchy?

Comment: @Ken White If the time overhead of reconstructing the leading zeros is a real issue, I have no hope of any lookup on commodity hardware being fast enough.

Comment: @Peter: We're still only talking about 12-character ASCII (not Unicode) UPCs here, and 1.9m fairly small rows. You're telling me that SQL Server 2008 is going to have performance issues with that? If so, MS needs to change the line of work for that team.

Comment: @PeterG. I agree, if the conversion of a numeric string to an int at the *client* is the limited factor there is a serious problem here.

Comment: @Randy, again, we're talking  about a relatively small number of rows (and relatively small rows, as well).

Comment: It isn't that numeric search is faster, it's that (say) 4 bytes is faster than 14 bytes [varchar(12) + 2 overhead]. At 12 digits he'd have to go with bigint (8 bytes), but the difference is still there.

Comment: @KenWhite The issue isn't with the storage type, the size nor the platform. The issue here seems firmly rooted in how the query is formed not to use an index. Nonetheless, if you're after performance, the `int` based lookup will beat the `varchar` lookup.

Comment: Where did this wander off into a major performance discussion? Again, we're talking about a relatively small number of rows with a very limited number of characters in that column. If you've optimized all of the rest of your code so that this is the major performance hit you have, kudos. I doubt that's the case, however. Agreed - an `int` based lookup will beat a `char` or `varchar` lookup, even adding in the additional conversions. Here, it's not worth the effort. (And Peter is the one that mentioned "space", not me.)

Comment: 1. I don't know the specifics of SQL Server but if Matthew PK is telling me the query is formulated in a way that forbids using an index, that is of course the first thing to address. 2. Max asked directly about improving the performance of his search.

Comment: @PeterG. I don't know what query is being used because the code posted is from an ORM, not SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I think storing as varchar(12) is probably fine. The #1 thing you can do to ensure the performance of your barcode queries is to make sure you have an index on the barcode column. Depending on your use of the data, you might consider making it a [clustered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Comment: If you have writes I **would not** recommend a clustered index. That will force your entire 1.9 million row table to re-sort on an `INSERT` because you're not `INSERT`ing sequential data.

Comment: I'd go with char(12) instead of varchar -- if it's always 12 bytes of data, you don't need the two-byte overhead per field.  Sure it's only two bytes, sure it's only 1.9M rows... but it sits in the indexes as well, and you are concerned with performance, so everything counts.

Comment: @MatthewPK: I don't agree with your "entire 1.9 million" part. Most inserts will likely cause only a very small portion of data to be reordered even if UPC is specified as clustered index. However, using clustered index for UPC is kind of irritating to me but ɹǝʇǝd had his statement protected by "Depending on your use of the data...". (If the data is loaded once and never insert/update/delete, plus the only possible query type is on whole UPCs, using a clustered index is a good choice.)

Comment: @Codism the use of a clustered index on *inherently unordered* data seems incorrect to me unless there is a specific reason to do it rather than a non-clustered index.

Comment: @MatthewPK: I agreed with you about the "clustered index on UPC" part if you read my previous comment more carefully (...using clustered index for UPC is kind of irritating to me...)

Comment: @Codism fair enough, but however many rows get reordered varies wildly with the input data.

Comment: Maybe I went too far in even bringing up the idea of a clustered index... I was imagining a scenario in which this was largely read-only data, the UPC is a natural key, the ProductId field is just a generated surrogate key and data is typically accessed by UPC (barcode scan).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your sql search criteria doesn't include a function, otherwise your query is not sargable.

I would guess that your reads far outnumber your writes, if the data is sensical without the leading zeros I would incur the cost of truncating them at write-time and searching on the exact value. Furthermore, UPC-A is numeric-only data. I would expect a more performant search on the numeric data than the `varchar` as you stated space is not a concern so you can even store **both** values if you desire.

You also need an index on the column.